# Failed to add a WMAsfReader into the FilterGraph

Tags: c#, filter, directshow

Add a WMAsfReader caused Error,HRESULT was -2147024770.The code is as follow:

```
sourceFilter = (IBaseFilter) new WMAsfReader();
((IFileSourceFilter)sourceFilter).Load(fileSource, null);
hr = filterGraph.AddFilter(sourceFilter, "WM ASF Reader");
MessageBox.Show(hr.ToString());
```

When I run this code on Win10 with WMP,it works well;but it does not work on Win7 without WMP.But I can find the "WM Asf Reader" in the registry,qasf.dll as well.What is the problem?Thanks.

Error Image:

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0):

The error code -2147024770 is `0x8007007E` `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND` "The specified module could not be found."

Such error for a Windows core component might indicate that something is broken in your Windows (e.g. certain application installed and registered the same DLL and then it was deinstalled - resulting in broken registration of the original module). It might also be caused by Windows 7 N version having no Windows Media in the default configuration, you are supposed to add the feature by installing a [Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16546).

> but it does not work on Win7 **without WMP**...
>
> ...The Media Feature Pack for Windows 7 N or Windows 7 KN will install Media Player **and related technologies** on a computer running...

It is not only Windows Media Player missing in N editions, but also the underlying APIs, used by WM ASF Reader.

Comment: Add the features via Controll Panel?Can I add them in the c# program?

Comment: I improved the wording to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ok，I understand!Thank you!